# What is the correct way in Spring WS to configure own replacement of DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter?

Tags: spring, spring-ws

We have the situation we need to read the parameters sent to the Spring Ws endpoint before the endpoint method is reached. For this purpose we made a descendant of the class
`org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter`, for example in this way:

```java
public class MyMethodEndpointAdapter extends DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter {
    @Override
    protected Object[] getMethodArguments(
            MessageContext aMessageContext, MethodEndpoint aMethodEndpoint) throws Exception {
        Object[] locResult =  super.getMethodArguments(aMessageContext, aMethodEndpoint);
        MethodParameter[] parameters = aMethodEndpoint.getMethodParameters()
        Object locPayloadObject = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
            if (parameters[i].hasParameterAnnotation(RequestPayload.class)) {
                locPayloadObject = locResult[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        // ... some custom code here dealing with resolved request payload object
    }
}
```

The solution works well, but the real issue here is the configuration. We use the XML configurations to make the things more transparent and manageable, so we defined in the configuration file for web service following settings:

```
<bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter"
      class="somepackage.MyMethodEndpointAdapter"/>
```

but still after specifying it in this way, the original implementation DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter is instantiated too. Then there are two adapters which are checked and it depends on the order of the configuration loading, which one gets instantiated first - and which one then gets the request when the correct handling instance is evaluated. Even the definition of the bean with name instead of Id

```
<bean name="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter"
      class="somepackage.MyMethodEndpointAdapter"/>
```

did not help.
Going through with debugger I found out, there is generated the bean name for instantiation of the singletons, named `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0` which is used by the instantiated default instance. So, finally, after specification of the bean definition like

```
<bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter"
      name="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0"
      class="somepackage.MyMethodEndpointAdapter"/>
```

We were able to bring Spring to the situation, only one (our) adapter is instantiated and we get the expected behavior.

But this seems to be ugly to us, the dynamically generated name
`org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0` seems to be a unstable way how to reference the replaced adapter implementation.

Is there some better way how to do it to bring Spring to the situation not to instantiate the default adapter at all?

Comment: Why do you need to access the parameters in the first place? What is it you need to do with it? Also you really shouldn't be doing this in the endpoint adapter but rather in a `MethodArgumentResolver` (or write a custom one for `RequestPayload` annotation (extend the regular one for instance). However without knowing your usecase there might even be a better place to do things.

Comment: We did not redefine MethodErgumentResolver from the following reasons:

Comment: We did not redefine MethodArgumentResolver from following reasons:
1. It seems to be to me rather the way, how to resolve differently encoded objects from the message context in some other than the default format, than for the other ways of usage, we do not want to change some format resolution
2. in the other processing we might use the other resolved parameters as well, redefinition of `getMethodArguments` gives the possibility to work with all of them together
3. the general purpose was to make source object accessible also from other places, if necesary
But still it should be possible

Comment: 1. Is a wrong understanding it is even used for the default ones. 2. Only the parameter it applies to will be available, that is true, 3. Not sure why it wouldn't be available if using the `MethodArgumentResolver`. That being said the problem is probably due to having a `ws:annotation-driven` in there which does a default setup.